# Draft emails dissappeared from draft folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I saved a number of emails in my drafts folder.  Reason being, they were of a particularly sensitive nature and I wanted to keep them in case I needed them at a future date.  Today I noticed that two of them are now missing.  I cannot say for certain when I last saw them, other than certainly within the last month.  Both items could be up to two years old.  They are not in my deleted items and their content is of a nature I would not want to disclose to the infrastructure team to search Exchange for.

Does anybody have any idea if there is an automatic deletion policy on the drafts folder, and if so, how can I change it?

Also, they don't appear on the Web client, so it's not a synch issue.

Comment: Is this a company email account? The Drafts folder is not for "saving" things. It's where emails that you have begun writing but have not yet sent are saved until you hit Send on them. It is not a special protected zone.

Comment: Search all other folders to see if you accidentally moved it to other folders. If it was also missed from web mail and other folders, it's hard to restore them.Agree with the comment above, if you want to save the email, you can drag it to a local folder as a .msg file.